# How to see what Protractor tests is currently executing?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

In my Protractor test script, I use the usual notation:

```
describe("mytest") {
    ...
    it(" should do this") {
    ... 
    it(" should do that") {
```

I would like to be able to see what test and what part of each is currently running when I run them. Is there any option I can use to output test descriptions to the console?

Answer (score 14):

There is a reporter that should do what you are looking for. Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-spec-reporter and https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter/tree/master/examples/protractor

Answer (score 13):

You can use the --verbose option to print more information about your tests, but it will not tell you which test is currently being run.

I suggest you to create an issue if you want that feature. https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/new

```
$ ./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor protractor-config.js --verbose

------------------------------------
PID: 7985 (capability: chrome #1)
------------------------------------

Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub

angularjs homepage
    should greet the named user

    todo list
        should list todos
        should add a todo

Finished in 5.915 seconds
3 tests, 5 assertions, 0 failures
```

Comment: It's also possible to set it up into protractor-config.js with: `jasmineNodeOpts: {isVerbose: true}` ;)

Answer (score 0):

since protractor runs in node you can use `console.log`  as you normally would in javascript, for more console fun see the node [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/console.html)

I like to place any logs after functionality so that I know its been completed, so wrapping it inside of a `.then()` function seemed to work best for me

example:

```
element(elementToFind).click().then(function(){
    console.log("clicked element");
    continue();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I know I can use console.log but I need to get the test name dynamically or else I am going to have to manually add it for every test.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know the name of the spec currently rinning you could use: `jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.description`
and log it

Answer (score 0):

```
        console.log('\nTest spec: ' + __filename + '\n');
```

to log the test but no idea how to log the **it** being executed

Comment: ReferenceError: __filename is not defined